# Qt IDE Setting Breakpoints

Tags: c++, qt

I made a program (a very beginner type program). When i compile it, the IDE keeps on **Setting Break** and never runs the program. I have checked the program, for me it has no errors. Any suggestions what to do.

Here is the Bobwindow.cpp

```
#include "bobwindow.h"
 #include "ui_bobwindow.h"
 #include "askdialog.h"
 #include <QListWidgetItem>

 BobWindow::BobWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::BobWindow)
  {
      ui->setupUi(this);
      dialog= new AskDialog(this);
      item= new QListWidget(this);
  }

BobWindow::~BobWindow()
 {
     delete ui;
 }

  void BobWindow::on_actionAdd_Item_triggered()
  {
       dialog->show();
   }
  void BobWindow::showlist(QString &data)
  {
   QListWidgetItem *itm= new QListWidgetItem;

   QFont fnt;
   fnt.setFamily("Times");
   fnt.setPointSize(18);
   fnt.setItalic(true);
   itm->setText(data);
   itm->setSizeHint(QSize(0,25));
   itm->setFont(fnt);

   itm->setBackground(Qt::green);
   itm->setIcon(QIcon(":/pics/goku3.jpg"));

   item->addItem(itm);
   item->setIconSize(QSize(15,15));
```

}

here is the Askdialog.cpp file

```
#include "bobwindow.h"
#include "askdialog.h"
#include "ui_askdialog.h"

 AskDialog::AskDialog(QWidget *parent) :
     QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::AskDialog)
      {
      ui->setupUi(this);
      prog= new BobWindow;
    }

AskDialog::~AskDialog()
{    
    delete ui;
}

void AskDialog::on_dokbutton_clicked()
{
   ui->dokbutton->setEnabled(false);
   ui->dokbutton->setDefault(true);
   QString data=ui->dline->text();
   prog->showlist(data);
```

}

here is askdialog.h file

```
#ifndef ASKDIALOG_H
#define ASKDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

class BobWindow;

namespace Ui {
class AskDialog;
}

class AskDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AskDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void showdialog();
    ~AskDialog();

private slots:
    void on_dokbutton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::AskDialog *ui;
    BobWindow *prog;
};

#endif // ASKDIALOG_H
```

here  is Bobwindow.h file

```
#ifndef BOBWINDOW_H
#define BOBWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QListWidget>
#include "askdialog.h"
namespace Ui {
 class BobWindow;
}

 class BobWindow : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     explicit BobWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
     ~BobWindow();
     void showlist(QString &);

  private slots:
     void on_actionAdd_Item_triggered();

  private:
     Ui::BobWindow *ui;
     QListWidget *item;
    AskDialog *dialog;
 };

  #endif // BOBWINDOW_H
```

what should i do to fix it?

Comment: You forgot to tell which IDE you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Everything's fine. 
It breaks on the breakpoint because you have set breakpoints and running the program in debug mode (for sure).

Are there any breakpoints set by you? If so, remove them and run in debug mode.

Else, you can run the program in release mode. 
To run the program in release mode use: `Ctrl+R` shortcut key

More on shortcuts here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: No i haven't set any break points. But don't know why is it taking so long to compile.